# Count the values that are repeated, even those that are absent

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database which contains in index, the date in first column the name of a company and in second column the method it uses.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"name_normalized" : ["A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"],
             "method": ["K1","K2","K3","K1","K2","K3","K2","K3"]})
print(test)
```

My goal is to count all the method repetitions every two months but as the dates are not important I left the classical indexes because my problem is not there, I want to count the method repetitions including the times when the method is not there and so I want it to count me 0 for this one, the following code does not allow me to do that:

```
test.groupby(['name_normalized','method'])['method'].count()
```

My goal is to count all the method repetitions every two months but as the dates are not important I left the classical indexes because my problem is not there, I want to count the method repetitions including the times when the method is not there and so I want it to count 0 for this one, the following code does not allow me to do that.

Ideally it is the same result as the previous code except that this one contains for the company C the method K1 with as repetition 0 and those for all the lines of my dataframe.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where you left off, you can [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with `fill_value=0` for the missing repetitions:

```
>>> test.groupby(["name_normalized", "method"])["method"].count().unstack(fill_value=0)

method           K1  K2  K3
name_normalized
A                 1   1   1
B                 1   1   1
C                 0   1   1
```

or with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.name_normalized, df.method)

method           K1  K2  K3
name_normalized
A                 1   1   1
B                 1   1   1
C                 0   1   1
```

Comment: Indeed it works, it modifies a little the exit to which I expected but the result is there, thank you very much